# Deleting IE6 cookies programmatically

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-xp

Is there a way to delete IE6 cookies programaticaly?  I have come across solutions for IE7 and IE8 using something like `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2` but this does not work for IE6.  I've tried a simple batch file to delete the contents of temporary internet files folder but that fails due to some files being in use.

Comment: _tongue in cheek_: try deleting IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use the WinINET cache enumeration functions (FindFirstUrlCacheEntry, FindNextUrlCacheEntry) to enumerate the cookie store, then call DeleteUrlCacheEntry on each cookie.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201 has a related code sample to get you started.

There are many command line utilities that will do this if you're just looking for a scriptable solution and don't actually need to integrate the code into some larger project...

Comment: Yup.  ClearMyTracks was a feature added in IE7.  Its a function that just calls the Wininet functions, so you can easily duplicate it.